# The applications of Hasse-weil theorem

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Is there any body who knows what is the application of Hasse-Weil theorem in elliptic curves and cryptography?
Any help would be great thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hasse-Weil theorem is a generalized version of Hasse's theorem for other algebraic curves.  Hasse's Theorem is used for Elliptic Curves defined over finite fields in determining upper and lower bounds for the group order.  You only need to know the order of the finite field to do so.

If the order of the field is $q$ and the group order (number of points in the group) is $N$,

$$q+1-2{\sqrt q} ≤ N ≤ q+1+2{\sqrt q}$$

In terms of applications of this, this is especially useful in Shanks' Baby-Step Giant-Step method of solving the Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm problem, as it makes it relatively easy to estimate the group order.  Although other methods exist to find the exact group order (Schoof's Algorithm), this is less complex.

Comment: I would say that Schoof (as well as Elkies, Atkin) heavily also depend on the bound. After all, they are (to a great extent) about computing the residue class of $N$ modulo several primes $\ell$. When the product of those primes exceeds $4\sqrt q$ you are done by CRT.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: From a practical point of view you are certainly right. But the algorithm is still deterministic polynomial time if you use the trivial upper bound $2q+2$ instead

Comment: @ReneSchoof Of course! Thanks for making that clear. Glad to see that you have found your way to these parts of the interwebs.